# error for installing COMMIT package in anaconda 3

Tags: python, anaconda, commit

I am going to install commit framework (Convex Optimization Modeling for Microstructure Informed Tractography) on anaconda 3.

Here I explained the process that I did: 1st, I downloaded commit and then opened an anaconda prompt and went to the location that I downloaded the folder but when I run `pip install commit` I faced with this error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement commit. No
>   matching distribution found for commit.

I am grateful for any suggestion to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the binary downloaded on the folder why you need to run `pip install commit` That would download and install it again right?

Just run `pip install .` on the folder where you downloaded the package.

Comment: I did as you mentioned,

C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\NewProject\COMMITmaster>pip install . 
but I got following error: 
                                                            
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\B IN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2.                                     

I am a new user in python and any suggestion would be great for me.                                                                                                                         @ Kimmo Hintikka